# Select closest match in dictionary order

Tags: sql, sqlite

Supporse I have the fllowing table with words from a dictionary:

```
Word
---
cat
dog
giraffe
zebra
```

I would like to find a word, and if it doesn't exist, the closest before it in [dictionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) order, e.g. `aardvark` would return nothing, `cat` would return `cat`, `cow` would return `cat`, `horse` would return `giraffe`.

This should be relatively straightforward to search for using a BTREE index but I haven't figured out a way to do it. I'm using sqlite for this, but other engines are also acceptable.

I'm only interested in the dictionary order, i.e. the query should work exactly with the above examples. Other similarity metrics are of course nice, but are irrelevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have declared the column with the correct [collation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) for dictionary order (which might be the default, or `COLLATE NOCASE`, or a user-defined collation), getting an exact match is trivial:

```
SELECT Word FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = ?
```

and getting the closest before is easy:

```
SELECT MAX(Word) FROM Dictionary WHERE Word < ?
```

To get only the first result of these two queries, combine them with [UNION ALL](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), and use `LIMIT 1` so that the second query is ignored if the first one succeeds:

```
SELECT Word FROM Dictionary WHERE Word = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(Word) FROM Dictionary WHERE Word < ?
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Do you know whether your second query can make use of some index on the words so it performs well?

Comment: To find out whether indexes are being used, use [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Answer (score -1):

this may helps you

```
select a.word,b.word from dictionary a, words b
where difference (a.word,'DOG')  in(3,4)
```

or you can use `soundex` function

Comment: That's an approximation, but I need the exact behavior.

Answer (score -1):

for approx match

```
select a.word,b.word from dictionary a, words b
where (b.word like '%'+right(a.word,2) )
```

or
for exact match

```
select a.word,b.word from dictionary a, words b
where soundex(a.word)=soundex(b.word) or
```